# Convert char to byte c++

Tags: c++, byte, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a char arry to a Byte (the microsoft type, I'm working with visual studio). The fact is that I want to fill in a [DCB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure for serial port communication and I get back the informations from a .ini file. The datas are saved in a char temporary buffer. Some values in the DCB port settings require to be in byte. I tried many ways without success. The datas are well retrieved from the .ini but I have some problem to convert them to byte.

I could convert the numeric values to integer but they also have to be byte.

And the process->read method is a personnal implementation of GetPrivateProfileString.

```
char res[10];
printf("\nReading port settings of %s\n", comName);
processFileConfig->read(comName, "baudrate", "9600", res, sizeof(res));
baudr = atoi(res);

processFileConfig->read(comName, "parity", "N", res, sizeof(res));
parity = (BYTE)res;
std::cout << "size of Parity : ";
std::cout << sizeof(parity) <<std::endl;
std::cout << "content of Parity : ";
std::cout << parity <<std::endl;

processFileConfig->read(comName, "byteSize", "8", res, sizeof(res));
byteSize = atoi(res);
std::cout << "biteSize : ";
std::cout << byteSize <<std::endl;


processFileConfig->read(comName, "stopBits", "1", res, sizeof(res));
stopBits = atoi(res);
std::cout << "stopBits : ";
std::cout << stopBits <<std::endl;

portSettings.DCBlength = sizeof(portSettings);
portSettings.BaudRate = baudr; //this one is OK
portSettings.ByteSize = byteSize; // returns 
portSettings.Parity = parity; // returns nothing
portSettings.StopBits = stopBits; // returns a smiley :)
```

And an example of my `file.ini` :

```
[COM1]
baudrate=15000
byteSize=8
stopBits=1
parity=N
```

EDIT : the res buffer returns the good values from the .ini. Everything is OK on this side. I just need to convert the last three values (byteSize, stopBits and parity) to unsigned long.

Comment: What do you mean by "some problem", you gotta be specific. Simple google on "WinAPI Byte" points to [MSND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) which states *"BYTE - A byte (8 bits). This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows: typedef unsigned char BYTE;"*. I am not even sure what problem can you get with it.

Comment: "some problem" : well, I cannot convert it :p    I also watched msdn byte with unisgned long. And I tried to convert the returned buffer (res) to unsigned long buffer.

Comment: Well @Mr. Stark you seem like you do not even know what is wrong. You kind of cannot be helped. I am very tempted to say "Yes you can! You just need believe in yourself." But instead a professional "Please post an error message, or the expected and actual output. Preferably with a working sscce."

Comment: xD I tried many things but I'm always lost with datatypes conversion. If you had an additional link which explains I take it ;)   And to reformulate my problem, I would say that I want to convert a char array to an unsigne long value.

Comment: Code. (Which you gave.) Input. Observed output. Expected output. That's the absolute minimum.

Comment: I've read this code twice now, and am utterly confused what you *want*. I see an error C-style casting a `char[10]` to `BYTE`. Why you're doing this, and what you want out of it I'm clueless on. There is no decl for `parity`, so heaven knows what that even is. it *looks* like the DCB interface expects a *flag*, but its honestly hard to say.

Comment: I thought it was enough explicit. I'm gonna adjust it ;)

Comment: You know [**`GetPrivateProfileInt`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724345(v=vs.85).aspx) will read those *numbers* for you, right?

Comment: @WhozCraig : I've edited with DCB MSDN link. It expects a byte or unsigned long value. I know cast is not very nice but I just tried to do something, even if very bad ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your current code attempts to convert a pointer to the buffer into a `BYTE`. What you need to do is parse the buffer with `strtoul()`, and cast *that* into a `BYTE`.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it. It was easy finally, I don't know why i blocked on it ^^
I created an intermediary  unsigned long var :

```
processFileConfig->read(comName, "parity", "N", res, sizeof(res));
unsigned long parity_ul = res[0];
parity = parity_ul;
std::cout << "parity : "; // 78 for 'N'
std::cout << parity <<std::endl;

portSettings.Parity = parity;

std::cout << "Parity : ";
std::cout << portSettings.Parity <<std::endl; // 'N' that's OK !
```

i did the same with the other unsigned values. I directly get the implicit cast (well I suppose this is the term) of atoi(res) to unsigned long value. According VS debugger the values are correctly entered in the portSettings but when I try to print them it fails. This is not perfect but if the code works I thinks it's OK.

Thanks to everybody